not able to display remaining units in google form when i choose a SKU from dropdown
i have a sheet attached to my google form. In my inventory sheet tab i have some sku and their quantity. I have a form attached to it. So whenever i or someone will choose a SKU in form from dropdown  choices, Google Form to display the remaining units for each SKU. When users open the form, they will see each SKU listed with the corresponding remaining units.
I have written a script but it is not showing anything.
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd8srpCG8HaD3BiAc9d25-Ucw32jwv9-cF3GkuNo9W0qO5doA/viewform
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OD1A1r8TqMzDiO1e0Btit5Ipt-2Vv_bunhAAWnjq7zk/edit?resourcekey=&gid=147247266#gid=147247266
i tried this script but no result, script attached to sheet

Please include the script in the body of the question.

Your Form has 7 choices (of which one is a duplicate) but the "Inventory" sheet has only 2 sku. Would you please ensure that the sample data is consistent with the form.

You want to update a Google Form dropdown to show the available qty for each dropdown item.

/*
//  update dropdown options for current stock quantity
//  IMPORTANT: include all SKU on "Inventory" even if qty = zero
*/

function updateForm() {
  
  var form = FormApp.openById("1gW-UZIBM6HYlx-JQh_MQTKhbNxVSrtPWWlv_4gEVmmM");
  var items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
  
  if (items.length === 0) {
    // Logger.log('No dropdown items found in the form.');
    return;
  }

  var item = items[0].asListItem();
  var choices = item.getChoices();
  var mapChoices = choices.map(v=>v.getValue())
  // Logger.log(mapChoices) // DEBUG
  
  // get the Inventory and qty data
  // All stock items must be included even if value = 0
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // delete the header row
  data = data.slice(1)
  // Logger.log(data) // DEBUG

  // create an array to hold new choices
  var updatedChoices = [];
  // loop through Inventory items
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var sku = data[i][0]
    var qty = data[i][1]   
    updatedChoices.push(sku + " - Remaining Units: " + qty);
    
  }
  // Logger.log(updatedChoices) // DEBUG
  // Update the dropdown choices
  item.setChoiceValues(updatedChoices);
  Logger.log('Form updated successfully');
}


SAMPLE INVENTORY


SAMPLE FORM OUTPUT


i updated the sku and removed duplicate still not able to get any answer

What can I say, I used your code and your data. But let’s try again… 1) would you please provide an example of the outcome that you are expecting. 2) “still not able to get any answer” Would you please explain EXACTLY what you mean by this. Is the code failing? Is there an error message?

i want to make a form where i want to keep my product SKU in one row and units against each product sku in another row in one block/or in one questions.Thats i want to do that in google form,but i tried and failed

OK, you code did work... the first time; then after that when the Option looked like "LEDL050 - Remaining Units: 50". Sorry, I didn't notice that. I've reworked the script; you need to list all the SKUs in the Inventory tab even if the qty is zero.
